# Setting colors for the overflow menu

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to set the colors of the menu items for the overflow menu. The unselected style works just fine, but the first item shows up pre-selected, which means I get white text with a white icon on a white background. I can make it legible by setting the text color to black, but I still lose the icon, and anyway, I don't want a white background. I'm setting these in the resource editor using the Command UIID, but it seems to be ignoring my settings for selected and/or pressed styles. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug in the code? (I'm using a modified version of the Blue theme.)

In the illustration, I have set a padding of 1 mm top and bottom, and a margin of 0 all the way around.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `bgTransparency` of the `CommandFocus` UIID to 0.

Comment: Thanks. Worked great.